# Comparing same string where one is from Flask and one from a sqlite3 database

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, sqlite, flask

In a login authentication module for a webapp, I'm trying to compare two values; a user entered password, and a password hash that is stored in a sqlite3 database (the hash just being the string 'password' for now).
The code is as follows:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['login'] == 'Login':
            username = request.form['username']
            user_password = request.form['password']
            #print query_db("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=?", username, one=True)[0]
            try:
                user = User(query_db("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=?", username, one=True)[0])
                print user.hash

            except IndexError:
                return "INVALID USERNAME!"
            hash = User.hash
            print hash
            #print whatisthis(hash)
            print user_password
            #print whatisthis(user_password)
            if user_password == hash:
                print "wooo!"
                #login_user(user)
                #flash("Logged in successfully.")
                return "LOGIN SUCCESS!"
                #return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("index"))
            else:
                return "INVALID PASSWORD!"
    return render_template("login.html")
```

`User` is a class that gets its attributes (like .hash) from the database after accessing the database through the ID. The print statements are simply for debugging, and they do show correctly the two strings (`hash` or `User.hash`, and `user_password`) to be identical when printing them to the terminal. However, they do not evaluate True in the if `user_password == hash` statement for some reason, always defaulting to the else case. Additionally, if I try to perform `.encode('base64')` on both strings, `user_password` properly changes to base64, however hash or `User.hash` stays the same even after the .encode!

Thanks a lot for your help with this odd problem!

Comment: Could you show the printed output and encoded result?

Comment: @laike9m This is the output of the above code:     * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
     * Restarting with reloader
    127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2014 02:11:40] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    password
    
    password
    127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2014 02:11:46] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: And this is the output when changing the prints to print hash.encode('base64') and print user_password.encode('base64'): `code`   127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2014 02:11:46] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 * Detected change in 'app.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
 * Detected change in 'app.py', reloading
 * Restarting with reloader
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2014 02:14:41] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
password

cGFzc3dvcmQ=

127.0.0.1 - - [24/Dec/2014 02:14:44] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 - `code` Thanks so much!

Comment: I think the problem is that `User.hash` is not a regular Python string, could you print `type(User.hash)`?

Comment: @laike9m For the type I get <type 'str'>. Thanks!

Comment: wait, are you sure you want to use `hash = User.hash` not `hash = user.hash`?

Comment: seeing the `repr()` of both `hash` and `password` would be more useful for debugging purposes -- and, that for what you are **actually** comparing, `User.hash`, **not** `user.hash` (capitalization, alas, matters!-)

Comment: YES! Of course, with hash = user.hash or just using user.hash in the if statement it works! Can't believe I missed that, been stuck on this for a good while now switching the encodings back and forth and whatnot, sigh... Thank you guys so much! (If you put it as an answer, I guess I can mark it as answered)

Comment: Another question would be, if I was referencing the class itself (who's default self.hash = "" and not "password"), and not an object of the class, why was I still getting the output of "password" from User.hash, and why was User.hash giving me anything in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User `hash = user.hash` rather than `hash = User.hash`.

```
>>> class User:
...     hash = ""
...     def __init__(self, hash):
...             self.hash = hash
...
>>> u1 = User("hash1")
>>> User.hash
''
>>> u1.hash
'hash1'
```

If you didn't set `User.hash` somewhere else in your code, `User.hash` will still has default value which is `''`. Therefore, since your `User.hash` is `"password"`, it is very likely to be set by other code.

Comment: People always make such mistakes :)

Comment: Another question would be, if I was referencing the class itself (who's default self.hash = "" and not "password"), and not an object of the class, why was I still getting the output of "password" from User.hash, and why was User.hash giving me anything in the first place?

Comment: @cloudcrypt You can paste the definition of `User`.

Comment: 'class User:
    ID = 0
    username = ""
    hash = ""
    pubkey = ""
    privkey = ""
    is_authenticated = False
    is_active = True
    is_anonymous = False
    def __init__(self, ID):
        (self.ID, self.username, self.email, self.hash, self.pubkey, self.privkey) = query_db("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID=?", ID, one=True)
    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.ID)'

Comment: @cloudcrypt That's it, `hash` is class attribute, so you can access it via `User.hash`.

Comment: If there were 2 separate instances of the User class, then which instances hash attribute would it give? Does this happen when there is only one instance of the class?